# Center two separate columns

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, multiple-columns

I have two columns, one is a jquery masonry grid (dynamic), and one is a separate column for tweets.

I want both columns to stay centered as the browser resizes.  I'm able to have the masonry grid stay centered as the browser grows/shrinks, however, my tweet column stays to the left, fixed.  I'd rather the tweet column move alongside the masonry grid.

How can I have both stay centered?

```
<div id='homepagecontainer' style="float:right; width:100%; margin-left:-280px;">

<div id="tweetaside" style="float:left; margin-left:10px;margin-top:-10px;width:260px;">
  <div style="width:250px;">
     Long list of Tweets!!
  </div>
</div>

<div id="masonrygrid" style="margin-left:280px;">
  <div id="homepagescroll" style="margin: 0 auto;">
      <center>
         Masonry Grid Data
      </center>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `#homepagecontainer{text-align:center;}` and then give `margin-left:280px;` to the `#tweetaside` but not to the `#masonrygrid`. I hope this will solve the problem.

Comment: So, if i remove the margin-left from masonry grid, change tweet aside margin-left to 280px and do the text-align for homepage, I end up with twitter column 280px from the left, and masonry grid overlapping the page...

Comment: hmm you are right, then give `margin-right: -280px` to `#masonrygrid` and check. remove `margin-left: 280px;`

Comment: that just makes masonry grid expand beyond the border to the right.  twitter column ends up staying fixed and to the left.  I want the twitter column to float side by side with the masonry grid in the center of the page...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Adapting an answer found on another post:

http://jsfiddle.net/jZEvL/

**HTML**

```
<div id="hideoverflow">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="inner">
           <div id="left">
               <p>Blah blah blah</p>
           </div>
           <div id="right">
               <p>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outer 
{ 
    overflow: hidden; 
}

#wrapper
{
    position:relative; 
    left:50%; 
    float:left;
}

#inner
{
    position:relative; 
    left:-50%; 
    float:left;
}

#left,
#right
{
    display:inline-table;
    height:200px;
}

#left
{
    margin-right:10px;     
    background-color:red;
}

#right
{
    margin:0;     
    background-color:blue;
}
```

I hope this time it fits your requirements. :)

Comment: Yeah, but i want the masonry grid to have a dynamic width.  Setting to 500 limits its size.  How can thag width be open ended?  Same with the container.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup; here are the basics. It could probably use some cleanup as I based it on a template (which I can't seem to find at the moment, sorry!) Note that I had some difficulties with the sidebar not stretching all the way down; I was able to work around this as it's in fixed position on my page but that might be an issue if you want your sidebar to scroll. This example has the sidebar on the right with the Masonry to the left of it, but it can go either way. If you do have the sidebar on the right you may want to alter your Masonry to collapse to the right by adding "isRTL: true" after "itemSelector: '.post'".

HTML:

```
<center>
<div class="main">
    <div id="fixed-left"></div>
    <div id="fixed-sidebar"> Your tweets </div>
    <div id="fixed-right"></div>
    <div id="fluid">
        <div id="posts"> Masonry grid </div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 96%;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#fixed-left {   /*-- this div is probably unnecessary, I just keep it in case I want to add a column --*/
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    width: 0;
}

#fixed-sidebar {
    float: right;   /*-- float: left if you want your sidebar to the left --*/
    display: inline;
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
}

#fixed-right {  /*-- this div is probably unnecessary, I just keep it in case I want to add a column --*/
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    width: 0;
}

#fluid {
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 250px;    /*-- same value as fixed-sidebar width; use margin-left if you want your sidebar to the left --*/
}
```

Hope this helps you!